# Remove the root from a binomial tree

Tags: trees

I have a binomial tree with height **k**.

How do I proof that when I remove the root, the result will be **k** new binomial trees, each with with a height from **0 to k-1**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply induction on $k$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your definition of "binomial tree is that geiven in Wikipedia (see Binomial Heap) it is defined recursiveley:

- A binomial tree of order 0 is a single node
- A binomial tree of order k has a root node whose children are roots of binomial trees of orders k−1, k−2, ..., 2, 1, 0 (in this order).

And a binomial tree of order $k$ has height $k$.

Thus what you need to prove follows trivially if the original tree has height 0; when you remove the (only) node, you are left with 0 trees.

And the second point of the definitions tells you what happens when you remove he root (leaving all the children as disjoint trees) of a tree of order $k > 0$.  That exactly matches the statement you need to prove.